# Ionic window.open is not working in ios device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have simply window.open(), user will search any thing in text field and will click on suggest link, so result will be open in device browser. My code is working fine in system browser(chrome) and in android device but in ios device its not working. Have a look of my code below .

```html
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) {
          var pageListElement = "";
          if(value.Name != undefined) {
             angular.forEach(value.Topics, function(value, key) {
              pageListElement = '<ion-item class="item-avatar-left energized item item-complex ionItemDisp" '+
                'id="page-list-item1" href="#" onclick="window.open(\'' + value.FirstURL + '\''+
                ', \'_system\', \'location=yes\'); return false;"><a class="item-content" ng-href="#" href="#">'+
                '<img src="' + value.Icon.URL + '"><h2energized>' + value.Text + '</h2energized>'+
              '</a></ion-item>';
               });
            } else if(value.FirstURL != undefined) {
                pageListElement = '<ion-item class="item-avatar-left energized item item-complex ionItemDisp" '+
                  'id="page-list-item1" href="#" onclick="window.open(\'' + value.FirstURL + '\''+
                  ', \'_system\', \'location=yes\'); return false;"><a class="item-content" ng-href="#" href="#">'+
                  '<img src="' + value.Icon.URL + '"><h2energized>' + value.Text + '</h2energized>'+
                '</a></ion-item>';
            } else {
              alert("unhandled query");
            }
          searchPageList.append(pageListElement);
        
        });
      }).
      error(function(data, status,headers, config) {
        alert("Status is " + status);
      });
    }
})
```

Please help me .

Comment: Try add inappbrowser plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
window.open('url', '_system');  
//Loads in the system browser 
window.open('url', '_blank');   
//Loads in the InAppBrowser
window.open('url', '_blank', 'location=no');
//Loads in the InAppBrowser with no location bar
window.open('url', '_self');
//Loads in the Cordova web view
```

more info: https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser

Answer (score 0):

If you are a dufus like me, I couldn't get the InAppBrowser plugin to work for nothing but the fix was really easy.

when you declare `cordova` at the top of the component you declare it as type `any` and no  intellisense so if you misspell something you won't be alerted.

I was using:

```
cordova.InaAppBrowser.open
```

I should have been using

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this way**

```
// cacitor
$ npm install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 
$ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser 
$ ionic cap sync

// cordova
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 
$ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser 


import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';

options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
    location: 'yes',//Or 'no' 
    hidden: 'no', //Or  'yes'
    clearcache: 'yes',
    clearsessioncache: 'yes',
    zoom: 'yes',//Android only ,shows browser zoom controls 
    hardwareback: 'yes',
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: 'no',
    shouldPauseOnSuspend: 'no', //Android only 
    closebuttoncaption: 'Close', //iOS only
    disallowoverscroll: 'no', //iOS only 
    toolbar: 'yes', //iOS only 
    enableViewportScale: 'no', //iOS only 
    allowInlineMediaPlayback: 'no',//iOS only 
    presentationstyle: 'pagesheet',//iOS only 
    fullscreen: 'yes',//Windows only    
  };

  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser)

  openWithInAppBrowser(url: string) {
    let target = "_blank";
    this.iab.create(url, target, this.options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works for me:

```
Platform: Web, Android, iOs
```

```html
<ion-col size="4" class="ion-text-center" (click)="openInMap()">
  <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/TWzQ6tMskmzAjUCy6?coh=178573&entry=tt" target="_system">
    <ion-icon class="zmdi zmdi-pin text_gradient" style="font-size: 70px;"></ion-icon>
  </a>
</ion-col>
```